# Making multiple Https requests with different methods in Node.js

Tags: node.js, https, runkit

I want to make a POST request that returns json data and then i want to get some keys values and then create a json string and then PUT that json sting to a url. And ideally would like this to happen every 30s. I have some code set up here https://runkit.com/lukejamison/5d2dfbf99644eb0013c64a56

```
var GeoJSON = require("geojson");
const stringify = require("json-stringify-pretty-compact");
var apikey = process.env.xapikey;

var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://app.detrack.com/api/v1/vehicles/view/all.json',
    headers: {
        'x-api-key': apikey,
    }
};

exports.endpoint = function(httpRequest, response) {
    if (!apikey){
        return response.end('"xapikey" key is missing.');
    }
    request(options, function (error, httpResponse, body){
        try{
            var jsonresponse = JSON.parse(body)
            var lat1 = jsonresponse.vehicles[0].lat
            var lng1 = jsonresponse.vehicles[0].lng
            response.end(stringify({ geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [lng1, lat1]}, type: "Feature", properties:{}}));
        }catch(ex){
            response.end(ex.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you use-case, Perform PUT request synchronously/asynchronously after the successful response from the POST request.

```
var request = require('request');
var GeoJSON = require("geojson");
const stringify = require("json-stringify-pretty-compact");
var apikey = process.env.xapikey;

//To create vehicle
function createVehicle(callback) {
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://app.detrack.com/api/v1/vehicles/view/all.json',
        headers: {
            'x-api-key': apikey,
        }
    };

    request(options, function (error, httpResponse, body){
        if(error) return callback(error);
        try{
            var jsonresponse = JSON.parse(body)
            var lat1 = jsonresponse.vehicles[0].lat
            var lng1 = jsonresponse.vehicles[0].lng
            const result = { geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [lng1, lat1]}, type: "Feature", properties:{}};
            callback(null, result);         
        }catch(ex){
            callback(ex)
        }
    }
}

//To update vehicle
function updateVehicle(data, callback) {
    var options = {
        method: 'PUT',
        url: '',
        headers: {
            'x-api-key': apikey,
        },
        body: data
    };  
    request(options, function (error, httpResponse, body){
        if(error) return callback(error);
        try{
            callback(null, body);           
        }catch(ex){
            callback(ex)
        }
    }
}


exports.endpoint = function(httpRequest, response) {
    if (!apikey){
        return response.end('"xapikey" key is missing.');
    }
    //To Create Vehicle
    createVehicle((error, createVehicleResponse) => {
        if(error) {
            response.end(error.message);
        }

        //To Update Vehicle synchronously, enpoint will return response once updateVehicle call responded back
        updateVehicle(createVehicleResponse, (error, updateVehicleResponse) => {
            if(error) {
                response.end(error.message);
            }
            response.end(stringify(createVehicleResponse));         
        }); 

        /*
        In order to exectue asynchronously, use the following snippet, which will retrun response after the createVehicle call the call updateVehicle in background
        createVehicle((error, createVehicleResponse) => {
            if(error) {
                response.end(error.message);
            }           
            updateVehicle(createVehicleResponse, (error, updateVehicleResponse) => {}); 
            response.end(stringify(createVehicleResponse));                 
        })    
        */

    })    
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help on that. But all I really need to do is make a post request and the put request every 30s I make a new document to show that. and all I need to add is the put request and have it run every 30 seconds. I added the new code below. so I just need to add the PUT request and have it all run every 30 seconds  https://dpaste.de/L6YC

Comment: Use scheduler and run jobs to PUT the request every 30second. Check out htis scheduler library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)

Comment: Thanks for that information but how do I add it in? Also, the second function is not working and it not making the `PUT` request with JSON string `result` the URL.